# Reset curl headers with C++

Tags: c++, curl

I have this code

```
struct curl_slist *pCURL_List = NULL;
pCURL_List = curl_slist_append(pCURL_List, "Content-type: application/x-amf");
curl_easy_setopt(m_pCURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, pCURL_List);
curl_easy_perform(m_pCURL);
```

and right after `curl_easy_perform(m_pCURL);` I need to reset the headers (the first part of the code). If I do `curl_slist_free_all(pCURL_List);` the next `curl_easy_perform(m_pCURL);` crashes the program.

I sure have the other parameters, the program is quite big and everything works EXCEPT calls after these lines.

Also, when I said that I need to reset the headers, I mean that I'd like curl to set back the old default values of Content-type. If I do

```
pCURL_List = curl_slist_append(pCURL_List, "Content-type:");
```

afaik it will delete the "Content-type" header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the crash, did you set CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER back to null before calling curl_easy_perform the second time? I'm thinking the list itself was freed but the CURL handle still has a pointer to the now invalid memory.

Comment: No I didn't set HTTPHEADER to null, thanks. (I didn't know that I needed to do this). And for the crash (that I have "fixed" by removing the free function), do you have then a fix ?

Comment: Btw I see that you're new, I don't advice you to answer to questions directly. I forgot if you can comment or not, but if you are NOT sure of what you are saying (like in this answer),  you should comment instead of answering. I'm telling you this because they will downvote you

Comment: This user has no comment privillige yet.

Comment: Awesome, this works. I have freed it and set the headers to null, it doesn't crash and the program works. :)